# Filtering using dplyr filter() on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing unique values of two variables:

```
df <- data.frame(V1=LETTERS,V2=c(1:26))
```

I'd like to filter another dataframe for values in `df$V1` and corresponding value of `df$V2`. This is what I have tried which obviously doesn't produce the desired result:

```
df2 <- data.frame(V1=c('A','A','B','B','A'),
                    V2=c(1,2,2,3,4))
df2 %>% filter(V1 %in% unique(df$V1) & V2 %in% unique(df$V2))
```

The result I am expecting post filtering is:

```
  V1 V2
1  A  1
2  B  2
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
merge(df,df2)
  V1 V2
1  A  1
2  B  2

library(tidyverse)
inner_join(df,df2)
  V1 V2
1  A  1
2  B  2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
df[df$V1 %in% unique(df2$V1),]

#   V1 V2
# 1  A  1
# 2  B  2
```

or

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% filter(V1 %in% unique(df2$V1))

#   V1 V2
# 1  A  1
# 2  B  2
```

In both cases above, you'll get the rows of `df` where `V1` of `df` matches the (unique) values of `V1` of `df2`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `intersect`

```
library(dplyr)
intersect(df, df2)
#  V1 V2
#1  A  1
#2  B  2
```

---

Or using `data.table` (assuming both are data.table objects and have the same attributes)

```
library(data.table)
fintersect(df, df2)
#   V1 V2
#1:  A  1
#2:  B  2
```